# RjxJs 7 - Subscribe Finalizer?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

We're using RxJs 7.4 and I'm wondering if there is a finalizer with the new `.subscribe()` syntax?

I will often have code such as:

```
this.service
  .someMethod()
  .subscribe({
    next: () => {
      nextThings();
      this.someBool = false;
    },
    error: err => {
      errorThings();
      this.someBool = false;
    }
  });
```

Is there a finalizer equivalent with this new `next/error` syntax so I only have to set `someBool` in one place?

Comment: Depends. There's `complete` - which will emit once the observable is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, take look at [pipeable](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators) operators. `finalize` is what you looking for.

sample:

````
this.service
      .someMethod()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.someBool = false))
      .subscribe({
        next: () => {
          nextThings();
          //not need this.someBool = false;
        },
        error: err => {
          errorThings();
          //not need this.someBool = false;
        }
      });```
````

Comment: I'd also suggest that you avoid using `subscribe` callbacks completely, and where possible avoid setting the value of local variables in reaction to Observable emissions.

Comment: Well, it is not a bad thing either. Just one of possible way we can use it. But yea, we can use it more nicely with e.g. async pipe

Comment: Can we explain further on this?  This is an HTTP call so subscribe is the end of the call chain.  I need to set a boolean to false in both conditions (next/error).

Comment: Using subscribe callbacks and modifying local variables are anti-patterns. The best practice is to use operators instead of callbacks and to only "de-Observable" the Observable at its point of consumption i.e. 95% of the time in the template via the async pipe.

Comment: For example, your boolean is consumed somewhere. If you need to refer to its value later, I'd advise using a BehaviorSubject (or even better, NgRx/other Redux implementation) to maintain Observable-ness. Local variables have a tendency to break and make unit testing much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right your question, I would start saying that `next` is part of a "finalizer" only if `this.service.someMethod()` returns an Observable which notifies **only once** and then `complete`s.

This is the case with Observables that map http calls, but not true in general terms.

In any case, as it has been already pointed in other responses, you can use the `finalize` operator if you want to execute one function when the Observable either `error`s or `complete`s.

Otherwise you can use the `complete` property of the Observer to run some logic when the Observable completes, like this

```
this.service
      .someMethod()
      .subscribe({
        next: () => {
          nextThings();
        },
        error: err => {
          errorThings();
        },
        complete: () => {
          // completeThings()
        }
      });
```

this does not solve the repetition of the logic, but is more accurate in terms of "finalizer".